# tensorial product with Lp

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let us consider E a finite-dimensional normed space on $\mathbb{R}$ and a real number $p\geq 1$.
Is it true that the projective tensorial product $E \widehat{\otimes}_\pi L^p(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is isometric to $L^p(\mathbb{R},E)$.

Thanks

Comment: Only for $p=1$.

Comment: Are you sure ? even if $E$ is finite dimensional ? Do you know any reference ?

Comment: For $p\neq 1$ and $E$ finite dimensional, they are isomorphic but not isometrically so.  If they were isometric, then by a simple compactness argument the same would hold for $E$ infinite dimensional.  I don't have access to a library at the moment so I can't give you a precise reference now.

Comment: Why close this? It's not a bad question for a non-expert to ask!

Answer (score 1):

See section The Natural Norm on the $p$-Integrable Functions in Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals by A. Defant and K. Floret,